# Mapping Leader to a Ctrl combination not working/being ignored in NeoVim mappings?

Tags: key-bindings, neovim, leader

I'm trying to map my leader to `<C-s>` and local leader to `<C-q>`, in my NeoVim (0.5.0) init.lua file. I know Ctrl-S and Ctrl-Q are software flow control, and I mainly use the terminal version of nvim (but I'm happy to disable software flow control in the terminal emulator), but strangely this mapping doesn't work in graphical nvim-qt either?

This indirect mapping does work for  as a  leader:

```
vim.api.nvim_set_keymap(  ''  ,  '<C-s>'  ,  '<Leader>'  ,  {noremap = false}  )
```

But directly trying to set it, does not:

```
vim.g.mapleader = "<C-s>"
```

I've tried many variations such as `\<C-s>` and `<C-S>` but none seem to work when called via the `vim.g.mapleader` function. That said, if I do an `echo mapleader` it does show `<C-s>`, but none of the actual bindings work, they only work if I have set the leader indirectly...

If I use something conventional like these, then the  mappings work...

```
vim.g.mapleader = " "
vim.g.mapleader = ","
vim.g.mapleader = "\\"
```

Any idea what is so special about trying to use `mapleader` with a Ctrl+Key combination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, after about a half  hour playing around, I remembered the whole "prefix with `<C-v>` to enter 'special' characters" thing.

So, this works:

```
vim.g.mapleader = "^S"
```

But you don't enter that as literal text, instead you must literally type it as:

```
vim.g.mapleader = <C-V><C-S>
```